# Dynamic created elements with different binding

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm very new to Angular 2. I'm Stuck with dynamic created elements. 
The app which i build can start multiple timers. When i click add timer a new ion-card is created with a different model.

The problem is now that i.e this.minutes has the same value for all timers the user creates.

The timers should run at the same time and should be stoped at different times. What is the correct way to do something like this in angular 2?

Any resources would be helpful!

```
    startTimer(t) {
    var eventDate: Date = new Date();
    this.timerStarted = true;
    this.hours = '00';
    this.minutes = '00';
    this.seconds = '00';
    var time = +moment(eventDate).add(t, 'minutes')
    var timer = Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {
                    this.diff = Math.floor((+time - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
                }).subscribe((x) => {
                    this.hours = this.getHours(this.diff);
                    this.minutes = this.getMinutes(this.diff);
                    this.seconds = this.getSeconds(this.diff);
                    if(this.diff  === 0) {
                      timer.unsubscribe();
                      this.hours = '00'
                      this.minutes = '00'
                      this.seconds = '01'
                    }
                });



  }

  addTimer(n) {
    this.timerNumber++;
    this.components.push({
      timerNum: "Timer" + this.timerNumber,
      comp: n
    });
    console.log(this.components)
  }
```

HTML

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-fab top right edge>
    <button ion-fab (click)="addTimer()"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4 *ngFor="let c of components">
          <ion-card class="card card-md">
            <ion-row>
            <ion-col class="col" col-6>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Produktname</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Produktname"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col class="col" col-6>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Zeit</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Zeit" [(ngModel)]="c.timer"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            </ion-row>

            <ion-item class="no-bottom-border item">
              <button ion-button large full clear class="timer-button timer-text" *ngIf="timerStarted">{{hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds}}</button>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="no-bottom-border">
              <button ion-button icon-left clear color="danger" small (click)="initTimer()" item-left>
                    <ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon>
                    Reset
                </button>
              <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="primary" *ngIf="h" (click)="pauseTimer()" item-right>
                    <ion-icon name="pause"></ion-icon>
                    Pause
                </button>
              <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="primary" (click)="resumeTimer()" item-right>
                    <ion-icon name="play"></ion-icon>
                    Resume
                </button>
              <button ion-button icon-left clear small color="primary" (click)="startTimer(c.timer)" item-right>
                    <ion-icon name="play"></ion-icon>
                    Start
                </button>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "this" to keep data. Attach timer data to each item. Somthing like that:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item.name}}
        <div *ngIf="item.timer">timer:{{item.x}}</div>
        <button (click)="start(item)">start</button>
        <button (click)="stop(item)">stop</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string;
  items = [{name: 'julia'}, {name: 'anna'}];

  start(item) {
    item.timer = Observable.interval(1000)
      .do(x=>{
        item.x = x;
      })
      .subscribe();
  }

  stop(item) {
    if (item.timer) {
      item.timer.unsubscribe();
      item.timer = null;
    }
  }

  constructor() {

  }
}
```